# How to allow for more than 5000 concurrent WebSocket connections in IIS 8 to a single Worker Process?

Tags: asp.net, websocket, iis-8

I've created an asp.net app for work with WebSockets. I published my app on IIS 8 (server specs: 64GB RAM, i7 processor). I could open up to 5000 concurrent connections during testing. The server wouldn't open new connections after this limit has been reached.

I can open more connections if I increase the number of Worker Processes, but I'm wondering if I can do so with a single Worker Process.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've successfully raised the per Worker Process limit to 50,000 by applying the following changes:

- open cmd as Administrator and run:

```
%windir%\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config /section:system.webserver/serverRuntime /appConcurrentRequestLimit:50000
```

- add the following block:

  ```xml
  <configuration>
    <system.web>
      <applicationPool maxConcurrentRequestsPerCPU="50000" />
    </system.web>
  </configuration>
  ```

  to these files:

  - `%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet.config`
  - `%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet.config`