# Limitation in concurrent websocket connection with SignalR in asp.net Core 2.0 on Azure

Tags: azure, websocket, signalr, asp.net-core-2.0, signalr.client

I have project with SignalR in ASP.net Core 2.0 and C#, there is no problem when I test it locally but when I upload project on Azure, there is limit on connections and I can make only 5 concurrent connection. I checked the web and I just found solutions like [Limiting performance factors of WebSocket in ASP.NET 4.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9982600/limiting-performance-factors-of-websocket-in-asp-net-4-5)
It shows some settings in web.config but I do not have web.config file. How can I increase my concurrent connections?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to SignalR guys, They found the problem.
That issue was happened because I was using free plan of Azure and it is limited to 5 WebSockets. By changing the plan, problem was solved.