# SignalR ASP.NET Core 5/3.1 Connections Limit

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr, asp.net-core-5.0

I am using ASP.NET 5.0 with SignalR, and also supporting it with a Redis backplane. My question is about the maximum number of connections one webserver can handle. In the docs, it's not mentioning how to calculate that value. I am expecting thousands of clients (mainly .NET applications) to connect to it. Any ideas?

Comment: Hello. You can read this performance wiki about connections limit: https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Performance

Comment: Thanks for the reply .. the link is related to .NET Framework and IIS 7 and not .NET Core .. I have already gone through it.

Comment: Where you will be hosting your app? You can also take a look in this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51242689/asp-net-core-signalr-websocket-connection-limit